# error when to create table using mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have used mysql workbench for create table. here when i create table

[image]
why i cannot add column at my table here ? like this is error and when i want to create it i got error like this
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```
CREATE TABLE `aliftesting`.`testing` (
);

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `aliftesting`.`testing` (
)
```

why i got this error in mydatabase ? thanks all

Comment: It looks to me  like an attempt to create a table  with no  columns.

Comment: ye but when i want add column i canot add new column why like that any idea for this problem

Comment: You cannot Crete a table with no columns